# How can I encrypt my android app

Tags: android

How can I encrypt my android app? My friends said he can see my android app's all class script. So, How can I encrypt my android app? and how can show class script in apk?

Comment: what do you mean by "class script" ?

Comment: I mean all activity.java files

Comment: You can make it harder (obfuscation) for other people to read your code but you can't prevent it. Android has to be able to open it and so can people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you create a "release" version of your APK (as opposed to a "debug version", it'll be obfuscated using proguard.  The debug version isn't, in order to make it easier for you to debug a running instance of your application.